# mysql php array to specific format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, format

I have the following code:

```
   <?php
//mysqli query here

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Amount ', 'type' => 'number'),
); 
$rows = array();
foreach($result as $row){
$temp = array();

$date1 = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['Date']);
$date2 = date_format($date1, 'm-d-Y');

$temp[] = array('v' => (string)'new Date("'.$date2.'")');
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $row['Amount']);
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$result->free();
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, true);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

This outputs the following data to a google line chart:

```
{"cols":[
{"label":"Reading Date","type":"date"},
{"label":"Reading ","type":"number"},
"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"new Date(10\/04\/2015)"},{"v":0.4}]},
{"c":[{"v":"new Date(02\/18\/2016)"},{"v":0.6}]}]}
```

However i need it to be in the exact following format for the chart to work properly:

```
{"cols":[
      {"label":"Reading Date","type":"date"},
      {"label":"Cl Reading(mg\/l) ","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":[
      {"c":[{"v":new Date("10/04/2015")},{"v":0.4}]},
      {"c":[{"v":new Date("02/18/2016")},{"v":0.6}]}
    ]}
```

so really im looking at just one line that needs changing but cant seem to get it into the format i need:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => (string)'new Date("'.$date2.'")');
```

Can anyone help me on this? I know its probably simple but just cant seem to get it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something more readable would help

```
<?php
//mysqli query here

$table = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Amount ', 'type' => 'number'),
    ),
    'rows' => array(),
);
foreach($result as $row){
    $date1 = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['Date']);
    $date2 = date_format($date1, 'Y, m, d');   // this
    $table['rows'][] = array(
        'c' => array(
            array('v' => '\'Date('.$date2.')\''),  // and this
            array('v' => (float) $row['Amount']),
        )
    );
}

$result->free();
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, true);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

now, what is it that needs changed?

**Edit:**
OK, I see now... you're not wanting to generate JSON, you think you're wanting to generate javascript..    Don't..  just keep it JSON...
(see [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation))

Generate the Date objects after the fact.   You'll have the date string.. just pass that do the Date constructor.

**Edit 2:**
see [Google Documentation - Dates and Times Using the Date String Representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation)
you just need to surround new Date(...) in quotes  (

**Edit 3:**
I updated my code block to reflect this the google documentation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brad Kent for pointing me in the right direction:

```
<?php

//mysql query 


    $table = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Amount ', 'type' => 'number'),

    ),
    'rows' => array(),
);
foreach($result as $row){
    $date1 = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['Date']);
    $date2 = date_format($date1, 'Y, m, d'); 
    $table['rows'][] = array(
        'c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Date('.$date2.')'), 
            array('v' => (float) $row['Amount'])

        )
    );
}

$result->free();
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, true);
echo $jsonTable;

    ?>
```